# Checking the distribution and value counts of a column based on group types in another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   Data_Entry   Type
0           1   Blue
1          10  Green
2           5  Green
3           2   Blue
4          12   Blue
5           2  Green
6           2    Red
7          50   Blue
8          32   Blue
9          76    Red
10         75    Red
11         12   Blue
```

I want to do some analysis around it in Python that would give me the:

1. Percentile distribution for each Type
2. The value counts of each type within a range

So for example for type **BLUE**, I would get the value counts as:

```
Value counts between 1-5 :  2
Value counts between 5-10:  0
Value counts between 10-15: 2
Value counts between 15-20: 0
Value counts between 20-25: 0
Value counts between 25-30: 0
Value counts between 30-35: 1
Value counts between 35-40: 0
Value counts between 40-45: 0
Value counts between 45-50: 0
Value counts between 50-55: 1
```

And I also would like to get a percentile distribution as well for each type separately.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Percentile dist:

At the moment I am using the following code to separate each type into it's own data frame and then applying the quantile function on it:

```
df_blue=df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Blue']

p_30_blue=df_blue.Data_Entry.quantile(0.30)
p_40_blue=df_blue.Data_Entry.quantile(0.40)
p_50_blue=df_blue.Data_Entry.quantile(0.50)
p_60_blue=df_blue.Data_Entry.quantile(0.60)
p_80_blue=df_blue.Data_Entry.quantile(0.80)
```

2. Value counts:

I used pythons inbuilt sql functions:

```
import pandasql as ps

    q= """SELECT Type,CASE 
             WHEN Data_entry <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
             WHEN Data_entry <= 50 and Data_entry >= 10 THEN '11-50' 
             WHEN Data_entry >= 50 and Data_entry <= 100 THEN '50-100' 
             ELSE '>=100' 
           END AS counts, 
           COUNT(*) AS n
    FROM df
    GROUP BY Type,CASE WHEN Data_entry <= 10 THEN '1-10' 
             WHEN Data_entry <= 50 and Data_entry >= 10 THEN '11-50' 
             WHEN Data_entry >= 50 and Data_entry <= 100 THEN '50-100' 
             ELSE '>=100' 
           END """
    
    result=ps.sqldf(q, locals())
```

Which gave me:

```
    Type counts  n
0   Blue   1-10  1
1   Blue  11-50  5
2  Green   1-10  1
3  Green  11-50  2
4    Red  11-50  1
5    Red  >=100  2
```

Is there a more efficient, better way of doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to look at how to bin your column then filter and count for number of records.

Comment: @malik hope you understand, SO is not a code writing service and you need to show you're effort in solving the problem to avoid question being closed.

Comment: hello, i added the code that i'm using so far to show what i have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something with `pd.cut` to classify `values` and `groupby`?

```
df.groupby([pd.cut(df.Data_Entry, bins=np.arange(0,100,5)), 'Type']).size().unstack('Type')
```

Output:

```
Type        Blue  Green  Red
Data_Entry                  
(0, 5]         2      2    1
(5, 10]        0      1    0
(10, 15]       2      0    0
(15, 20]       0      0    0
(20, 25]       0      0    0
(25, 30]       0      0    0
(30, 35]       1      0    0
(35, 40]       0      0    0
(40, 45]       0      0    0
(45, 50]       1      0    0
(50, 55]       0      0    0
(55, 60]       0      0    0
(60, 65]       0      0    0
(65, 70]       0      0    0
(70, 75]       0      0    1
(75, 80]       0      0    1
(80, 85]       0      0    0
(85, 90]       0      0    0
(90, 95]       0      0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create subsets from your dataframe that match your condition. For example for Data of values between 1 and 5 do `df[df['Data_Entry'] >= 1][df['Data_Entry'] <= 5]`. Then you could count like this: `df[df['Data_Entry'] >= 1][df['Data_Entry'] <= 5].value_counts()`. The return value can be converted into a dictionary: `dict(df[df['Data_Entry'] >= 1][df['Data_Entry'] <= 5].value_counts())`. From there it should be easy to also calculate percentages